# unexpected '@' in program (Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsobject

All of the sudden Xcode is giving me an error *"unexpected '@' in program"* at the beginning of my object `@interface`.

This is happening in a bunch of my objects that were previously working...

Here's an example  (with errors in comments)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ONCOChordDiamond.h"
@interface ONCOChordView : UIView   //// unexpected '@'  in program
{
    NSMutableArray* chordDiamonds;    
    NSUInteger      diamondWidth, diamondHeight;
}

@end                                /////unexpected '@' in program'
```

So why is Xcode giving me this error?  It seems like a bug.

Answer (score 12):

I doubt you're still having the issue, but if you are check the header file.  I pasted in code from the web in a class and the quotation marks weren't the standard " ".  The marks were stylized with an opening quote and a closing quote because it came from a webpage.  Retyping the quote marks fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for posting this comment; I struggled with a similiar issue for several hours and your comment resolved my issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You are including the header from a file that is not compiled as Objective C.

Comment: I had this problem while trying to #import the header of an NSString-categorty in an Objective-C++ (.mm) implementation-file.

It worked fine however after i moved the #import line to the corresponding header file.

Why that is?

Answer (score 5):

Check for syntax errors in the ONCOChordDiamond.h file. They may be highlighted for you if you run Product > Analyze in Xcode.

Importing a file with syntax errors could lead to the compiler not being able to parse the current file correctly, even if the current file's syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0):

When encountering this problem with NSString literals, Check that you have used quotation marks, as required.

```
 (eg. @"myString")
```

If you find your NSStrings are not correctly syntax coloured, you might check for the following offending characters.

```
" (QUOTATION MARK) 
″ (DOUBLE PRIME) 
“ (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) 
” (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK)
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had this issue and the offending line that was identified was nowhere near any string literals.

I **did** notice that some of the following lines were colored oddly (again, no string literals to blame), so I tested out putting a bogus string literal in the code just before the offending line.

```
NSString *whatever = @"";
```

Apparently, it convinced the compiler that the line **wasn't** screwed up, so it then compiled just fine without complaining. After that build, I was able to delete the bogus string variable and move on with my life.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was because the last quote was getting escaped out.  I was using a multiline string with a terminating "\" to eat up the end of line character.

```
[ string appendFormat:@"\n\
      vec4 position;\n\
      vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;\n\" ];
```

After I removed the mistaken "\" that ate up the last quote it worked.